# A thumbnail like Navigator for very long (horizontally) HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a static web page would has to be very long horizontally for display a sequence of images and text. (around 50000x1024 pixels in whole).

Would like to ask what is the easiest way to make a "always on top" navigator, which display a small thumbnail of the whole web page. When a user clicks on the thumbnail, the web page will scroll accordingly.

Are there any framework or tool or jquery plugin for doing this? Thank you very much.

Comment: do mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the jquery plugin http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/